# Extract month number?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a procedure where user inputs month e.g 'JAN' to extract data for that month. I want to compare the input month with month part in a date. This is what I got so far.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SavingsAccountsAllDetail
(@Yr INT=NULL,
@Mon CHAR(3)=NULL)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Year INT
    DECLARE @Month CHAR(3)

    SET @Year = @Yr
    SET @Month = @Mon
```

and comparing part.

```
datepart(year, A.DateOpen)=@Year AND datepart(month, A.DateOpen)=datepart(MM, @Month)
```

But when I execute my procedure it says

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string. Severity 16

Any idea on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `DATEPART` but passing it your property called `@Mon` which is a `CHAR(3)`, he cannot convert this `CHAR(3)` to `Date`, hence the error.

Your `@Mon` parameter should be an `Int` like `@Yr` and your query be

```
datepart(year, A.DateOpen)=@Year AND datepart(month, A.DateOpen) = @Month
```

Comment: I want the users to enter month in i.e 'JAN' format. How to compare this with month part of date?

Comment: Then check Pravin's answer, it's exactly what you're trying to do. Just be careful with that it might not work correctly depending on the locale of the computer (it could return Janvier if the locale is French for example), and it's probably way safer in terms of code to use the month number.

Answer (score 1):

Your `@Year` and `@Month` variables are not dates. They are string representations of parts of a date.

When you extract the dateparts from `A.DateOpen` you can directly compare that to those variables:

```
datepart(year, A.DateOpen)=@Year AND datepart(month, A.DateOpen)=@Month
```

However, `datepart` will return a numerical value and you want to compare to text (eg 'JAN'). Consider adding the 'DateName()' function, and changing the line to:

```
datepart(year, A.DateOpen)=@Year AND left(datename(month, A.DateOpen), 3)=@Month
```

Comment: Just noticed that which ever date used it shows only JAN month. Try this: SELECT 
datepart(year, '4/26/2015 12:00:00 AM'), left(datename(month, datepart(month, '4/26/2015 12:00:00 AM')), 3)

Comment: @DeEDEe You're right; I had accidentally left a `DatePart()` in there... Last statement changed, should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `datepart` use `datename`, It will now return you name of month instead of Month index (i.e., 12 for December)

Then get for first three letters of returned month to compare with you input string

Use this for comparing

```
 datepart(year, A.DateOpen)=@Year AND left(datename(month, A.DateOpen),3)=@Month
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this like query

```
DECLARE @inpMonth CHAR(3) = 'SEP'
SELECT CASE WHEN @inpMonth = FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MMM') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [res]
```

I use in SQL SERVER 2012

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the error from

```
datepart(month, A.DateOpen)=datepart(MM, @Month)
```

as `@Month` can have the value `Jan`, `Feb` etc.. which `sql server` couldn't convert to a proper date.

Assign proper value to `@month` from `@Mon` like;

```
DECLARE @Month int
select @Month = 
    case @Mon
    when 'Jan' then 1  
    when 'Feb' then 2  
    when 'Mar' then 3  
    when 'Apr' then 4  
    when 'May' then 5  
    when 'Jun' then 6  
    when 'Jul' then 7  
    when 'Aug' then 8  
    when 'Sep' then 9  
    when 'Oct' then 10  
    when 'Nov' then 11  
    when 'Dec' then 12 
    else  0 
end
```

and use `@month` in the query like;

```
datepart(year, A.DateOpen) = @Year AND datepart(month, A.DateOpen) = @Month
```